# How to get water mark background image in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I wand to set institute logo as a background image and image opacity 0.3 on jasper report.
I am able to set background image as a regular image but I am unable to set opacity

example [image]

Comment: Maybe this two posts help you: [How to create watermark in the background band in iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14083270/876298) & [Semi-transparent (translucent) background color ignored in jasper reports pdf expor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29458133/876298)

Comment: Sir I already try above link which is works for text not image. If use custom style then problem maybe solve but I can't use custom style in jasper

Comment: You can apply attributes without adding styles

Comment: opacity attribute is not available on jasper report image tag

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm late to the party or not but you can do following to apply opacity:

1. Put image inside band under Background tag
2. Put a white color rectangle on top of image inside band under background tag.
3. Play with opacity of added rectangle to change opacity of background image.

Bonus: You can add a colored rectangle instead of white to add colored-filter   effects.